# this.value only returning first two characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to find the value of all elements with the class bm-user-label, and put it into a javascript array.  However when I do this I only get the first two characters of the value field.  For instance for:

```
value="30bb3825e8f631cc6075c0f87bb4978c"
```

I get returned

```
30
```

The DOM looks like

```
<li value="30bb3825e8f631cc6075c0f87bb4978c" class="cboxElement bm-user-label">first</li>
```

And my javascript is:

```
var com_labels = $('.bm-user-label').map(function() {
     return(this.value);
}).get();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<li>` elements are not defined to have a value. You should get this attribute using `this.getAttribute("value")` instead.

Comment: Might be better to use the data attribute instead of the value attribute. It's a small thing, but it makes the html more semantic.

Answer (score 4):

In an effort to follow the doctype standards, you should use data attributes for non-native attributes:

```
<li data-value="30bb3825e8f631cc6075c0f87bb4978c" class="cboxElement bm-user-label">first</li>
```

And query it as such:

```
var com_labels = $('.bm-user-label').map(function() {
     return($(this).data('value'));
}).get();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sTdWY/

Comment: +1 for improving on scrappedcola's answer with the data attribute